# How to send Date and Time separately to backend in swift?

Tags: swift, time

`fromDateLabel.text` getting date and time from datepicker.. which i need to send date and time seperatedly to backend

when i do `DateFormatter` date is coming correctly but i**n time, only two digit values are working means time taking 10, 11, 12 O'Clocks. if i take 1,2,3,4,5 its not working**

**code:** here single digit time not working

```
    var fromDateArr = fromDateLabel.text!.components(separatedBy: ",")
    fromDate = fromDateArr[0]
    fromTime = fromDateArr[1].replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

        let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
        let showDateFrom = inputFormatter.date(from: fromDate)
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        formateFromdate = inputFormatter.string(from: showDateFrom!)
        print("formate from date \(formateFromdate)")
```

**if i formate date and time like below nothing works**

```
        let fromDate = fromDateLabel.text!
        let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm:ssa"
        guard  let showDateFrom = inputFormatter.date(from: fromDate) else { return }

        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" // -> to get date only
        formateFromdate = inputFormatter.string(from: showDateFrom)
        print("from date: ", formateFromdate)

        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" // -> to get time only
        formateFromTime = inputFormatter.string(from: showDateFrom)

        print("from time")
```

How to send date and time separately to backend.. with 1 to 12hrs time

**NOTE**: if its 8 o clock then the out put time should be 08:15, not 8:15.. thats the issue.. please help me with code

Comment: what is the format on fromDateLabel.text!

Comment: @BenRockey this is the output `total txtfld text Optional("8/18/20, 2:23 PM")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var txtdate: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.txtdate.setInputViewDatePicker(target: self, selector: #selector(tapDone)) //1
    }

    @objc func tapDone() {
        if let datePicker = self.txtdate.inputView as? UIDatePicker {
            let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
            dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm a"
            self.txtdate.text = dateformatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        }
        self.txtdate.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func showClk(_ sender: Any) {
        let fromDate = txtdate.text!
        print(fromDate)
        let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm a"
        guard  let showDateFrom = inputFormatter.date(from: fromDate) else { return }

        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" // -> to get date only
        let formateFromdate = inputFormatter.string(from: showDateFrom)
        print("from date: ", formateFromdate)

        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" // -> to get time only
        let formateFromTime = inputFormatter.string(from: showDateFrom)

        print("from time" ,formateFromTime)
    }
}

extension UITextField {

    func setInputViewDatePicker(target: Any, selector: Selector) {
        // Create a UIDatePicker object and assign to inputView
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 216))//1
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        self.inputView = datePicker
    
        // Create a toolbar and assign it to inputAccessoryView
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: 44.0))
        let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(tapCancel))
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: target, action: selector)
        toolBar.setItems([cancel, flexible, barButton], animated: false)
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    @objc func tapCancel() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: error `{
    Code = 400;
    Message = "Text '12:00:00AM' could not be parsed at index 2";
}]`

Comment: i think ur code and my 2nd code is same.. so the above error coming in console

Comment: yes the only difference is "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm a" . fromDateLabel.text! format should be same.. you says that it is like "8/18/20, 2:23 PM".

Comment: why you add hardcode date.. textfield date and time should separate

Comment: you said that the format of date in text field is "8/18/20, 2:23 PM"... you can change hardcoded date to.... let fromDate = fromDateLabel.text!

Comment: yes, in my 2nd code issue is time `shouldbe 02:23`.. but we r getting 2:23 thats the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219954/discussion-between-ben-rockey-and-iosapp).